# Automata Theory books

Tags: automata

Please suggest me some good books on "Formal languages and Automata Theory".

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend this book. It's used for the CMU course.

http://www.amazon.ca/Introduction-Theory-Computation-Second-Michael/dp/0534950973

but this one is the gold standard

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hopcroft-ullman-79-cover.jpg

Answer (score 6):

The book here is [Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages and Computation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321462254) by Hopcroft, Motwani and Ullman (Ullman is one of the dragon book guys). (I recommend finding an older edition in your library if you can; the older editions were shorter and I don't see much value in the additional material in the new editions).

Another great book is [Introduction to the Theory of Computation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0534950973) by Sipser.

You can not go wrong with one of those two.

Answer (score 4):

depends what level you're looking for. we used Peter Linz's An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata, Fourth Edition in my intro class and i liked it.

[google books preview](http://books.google.ca/books?id=KOo4NpfTEAIC&dq=formal+languages+peter+linz&printsec=frontcover&source=in&hl=en&ei=uQNCS420IM36_Aa-8pjzCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=12&ved=0CEEQ6AEwCw#v=onepage&q=&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

Some material by Rosenberg:

http://www.springer.com/math/cse/book/978-0-387-09638-4